# PHP program hanging when cURL in while loop

Tags: php, json, curl

So I'm trying to get all of the json data from an API, however I can't reliably get the loop to end while getting all the data. Here is the code I currently have

```
$num = 1000;
$continue = TRUE;
$loops = 0;

while ($continue == TRUE AND $loops < 3) { 
    // initialize cURL session
    $ch = curl_init($host . '/' . $service . '?limit=500' . '&offset=' . ($num)) or die("Could not connect to API.");

    // set headers
    $httpHeader = array(
            'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            'Accept: application/json',
            'SecureUrl: ' . $secureUrl,
            'PrivateKey: ' . $privateKey,
            'Token: ' . $token,
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpHeader);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);


    $json = json_decode($response, TRUE);

    if ( isset($json[0]["Key"] )) {
        $continue = FALSE;
    }

    $num += 500;

    $loops++;

    curl_close($ch);
}
```

All of the variables are previously declared. I have been able to get the json data if I stop the while loop once `num` reaches a certain number, but that will not always be reliable. The code stops outputting json data around the 3rd or 4th execution, and just hangs there for up to 5 minutes before spewing a bunch of errors.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: I have found my issue. No matter what the parameter of my if statement is, my program refuses to change `$continue` to `FALSE`. I have updated my code, if someone could reason as to why that would be great. Note that even if I set the if parameter to `0 == 0`, `$continue` will still not change.

Edit 2: I have solved all my problems.

Comment: What are the errors you're getting?

Comment: I don't see where you are outputting any data, you are how ever overwriting your data `$json` with every loop which I don't think you want to be doing.

Comment: @aynber "Offset amount exceeds the total number of records."

Comment: @cmorrissey I usually have the second option commented out so I can see the json output to the screen.

I also will be using the decoded json inside the for loop later so it does not matter that it's being overwritten each time as I only need it briefly.

Comment: You should not put a curl call inside a loop like this, you are asking an external address that cannot be reachable , or can even block your constant request. You should handle it with some callback. For the hanging problem, and by your comment, your `$num += 500` determining your offset isn't working for your logic

Comment: You probably want to check for that message when processing your curl response, then. If you hit that message, then set `$continue = FALSE`. If you can get the number of total records from the site somehow, that would be even better.

Comment: @GIJOW I'm not entirely sure why I shouldn't have it in a loop. The address is reachable and I am still staying within their API limit, even with it being in a loop. However, I'm new to PHP so I could be entirely wrong. I also fixed the offset issue.


@aynber Unfortunately, there is not a way to get the total records through their API. I will try setting `$continue = FALSE` when I hit the message.

Answer (score 0):

From the error you are receiving it seems that the site is handling the invalid URL and responding with an error page. Therefore the `$response` is not falsey and `$continue` is always true.

You should check the result better. Either check for errors strings that you know would indicate no more records (could be problematic) or check the headers. Hopefully the API will return with an errored status code or something.

Even after you do that I would add a sanity check to your `while`. Have some counter that will stop the loop from going out of hand:

```
$loops = 100;
while( $continue AND $loops > 0 ){
    ...
    //Your code
    ...
    $loops--;
}
```

This will ensure you loop 100 times at the very most.